# Dynamic jQuery Tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, tooltip

I have a pretty specific request. I have been looking through some other posts, but can't find a definitive answer on this, so help is appreciated.

I'm looking to get a jQuery tooltip that when hovered is a normal tooltip with the text centered. However, when you click the element, the tooltip widens to the left (the text would remain centered so it'd be appear to be moving left as the tooltips center moved left) and a dropdown menu slides out beneath the tooltip. I am still on the fence on whether or not the widening is going to be necessary, but I want the ability to have the dropdown on click.

Any and all help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT***** I have written some code that I can't really get to work. Right now I'm just trying to work it out with divs, hoping I can replace the "toolTip" div with a tooltip shape instead of just a box, but I want to get things working before I worry about that. Any help on the following code is appreciated. Thanks!

I apologize in advance for the lack of some indentation and stuff, I don't know why my code doesn't ever copy/paste well into here.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div class="topIconNew">
</div>

<div class="topTip">
</div>

<div class="topDrop">
</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#wrapper {
margin:0 auto;
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}  

.topIconNew {
background-color:red;
border:solid 1px #444444;
width:20px;
height:20px;
position:fixed;
    top:50px;
    left:450px;
cursor:pointer    
}

.topTip {
background-color:#d3d3d3;
border:solid 1px #444444;
width:80px;
height:20px;
position:fixed;
    top:70px;
    left:450px;    
}    

.topDrop {
background-color:#ffffff;
border:solid 1px #555555;
width:100px;
height:300px;
position:fixed;
    top:90px;
    left:450px;        
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// tooltip hover
$("div.topIconNew").hover(
    function(){
        $("div.topTip").show();
    }
);        

//tooltip widening and dropdown menu

$("div.topIconNew").click(
    function(){
        //permanent tooltip
        $("div.topTip").show();
    },    
    function(){
        //widen tooltip
$("div.topTip").animate({width:200},"fast");
    },        
    function() {
        //show dropdown
        $("div.topDrop").slideDown(300);
    }
);
$("div.wrapper").click(
    function(){
        //hide dropdown (hide simultaneously)
        $("div.topDrop").hide();
    }
    function(){
        //hide tooltip (hide simultaneously)
        $("div.topTip").hide();
    {        
);

});
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8Qc3d/1/ Should get you started

Comment: Thank you!!!! I will have a look through what you did. See all the things I was missing and doing wrong. I really appreciate that.

Comment: Quick question for you(again thank you for that help! Not only does it work, but helps me understand jQuery more) or anyone else I suppose. The click "wrapper" div to hide everything. That is my base container for the page... and in terms of z-index, I believe it's beneath everything. I am going to guess this is why the current code doesn't work when clicking outside. What would be the solution here? Is there a "clickOutside" event in jQuery? I'll go search for that now in fact...

Comment: I think its because you have fixed position. These arent really "IN" the wrapper box so the box doesn't have a width/height. I'd set `$(document).click()` to do the hide but you will have to check the event.target (I think) to make sure the click wasn't in one of the divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming from scratch I'd first build

1. A dropdown menu class that can be absolutely positioned
2. A tooltip class that can be absolutely positioned

It would be important for these classes to be self contained e.g. the dropdown should handle all bind events etc... First I'd hook up a hover element over whatever triggers the tooltip then position the tooltip and set the text. I'd then attach an onClick event to the same item and inside that I'd:

1. Flag the tooltip as "hover out no longer destroys it" (probably use an external click on the document instead)
2. Run an animate on the tooltip object that both sets the x position to x-200 (for instance) and also sets the width to with+200 (`.animate({x: '-=200', width: '+=200'})`)
3. I'd attach an event listener on animate so at the end of the animation I then attach the dropdown relative to the tooltip

If you code them separately it should be easy to tie them all together. You really just have to focus on the main evens in such a system:

1. Mouseover on item for tooltip
2. Mouseout on item for tooltip
3. Click on item to fly out tooltip and flag for permanence
4. Attaching the dropdown
5. Responding to dropdown events

Comment: Thank you for the help! I appreciate the guidance. I'm a bit new to jQuery, so this will be a good learning experience. Wish me luck, ha.

Comment: If you have any other questions feel free to post them. I'd use jsfiddle.net to share code if you need something more in depth (plus it's just a cool tool to mess around with javascript/jquery)

Comment: Will do. I appreciate the jsfiddle suggestion. I've signed up for that now. Would you happen to know of a good simple tooltip and dropdown? I've just always been better at learning when manipulating examples to see what's going on and how to get things to work.

Comment: jsfiddle is a neat tool, and great for comments (which can't hold much code) and to help out people answering your question.  Do try to keep your questions and answers self-contained as much as possible, including code (as you have in this question).  If someone has to go to jsfiddle.com to understand your question or answer, it probably isn't as distilled as it should be.  It's good for greater context, but try to post the pertinent snippets on SO directly.

Comment: Okay, thanks Merlyn. I think the jsfiddle tool is still pretty neat regardless, since it enables me to edit all the code in one window and see the results at the same time... less switching back and forth, which is nice. Also, did my edit bump my post to the top of SO (does your comment due the same)? I'm afraid that this post is just buried and won't get any responses with the new code. I assume it's against the rules to create a new post, framing the same question, but with all the code?

Comment: Bootstrap (on github) has a pretty good tooltip class I've modified before. Havent used any easy dropdowns recently but I'm sure they are out there.

Comment: Do you happen to know which one you used? Also, is the method of creating the tooltip also jQuery, right? Since I don't think you can create the box with the pointer in css or anything, unless you used an image. If that's the case... once I get my code working, using a regular div as a tooltip, I could then DL and reference a tooltip plugin to have it create the tooltip image (box with a pointer) rather than regular div. And if so, to change the tooltip image, I'd need to change the javascript behind the jQuery tooltip plugin I DLed... yes? I feel like I'm asking dumb questions, but oh well.